# plot k-means clustering graph

Tags: python

```
data = [[4,1,3,4,5,0,9,10][12,3,5,1,4,9,0,9]...] 

N_CLUSTERS = 8

kmeans = KMeans(init='k-means++', n_clusters=N_CLUSTERS, n_init=60)

kmeans.fit(data)

pred_classes = kmeans.predict(data)
```

The data is normalized between 1 and 13. How can I plot the kmeans clustering?
I am trying to follow this tutorial (right graph) http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_kmeans_silhouette_analysis.html
but this example is only for two features and I have 8.

Comment: You could first transform your data into 2D-space using PCA and then plot them as per the tutorial.